# Strange available and purgeable space on High Sierra

Tags: mac, hard-drive, encryption

My Mac has been complaining about low disk space in recent days. I tried deleting lots of huge files and folders (more than 20 or 30 GB of them) but I still got the complaint and the free space does not increase. It seems like what I deleted has become purgeable content instead of free space.

Here is my storage overview:
[image]

Cool, more than 60GB of available space. Not quite, here is what is shown in my disk utility:

[image]

Okay, more than 60GB are purgeable. No matter how many files I deleted from the system, the purgeable content is increased, not the free space.

Do you know what is going on? I suspect it is related to the encryption process because it is running at the moment (the progress is 80% at the moment), but I am not sure.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you answered you own question already. The part "More then one day remaining" made me lough. So come back tomorrow.

Comment: well, I suspect it but the thing is that I don't know if that is the root cause. The encryption has been running for more than 5 days though...

Comment: OMG 5 days :)  that is crazy

Comment: Yeah, it's weird

Comment: It should not take more than few hours, not days, afraid your disk has a problem

Comment: The long duration is explained by the sheer lack of real space - 1.64GB free, your drive is choking. When you deleted files to free up space, did you actually empty the Trash afterwards? Purgeable space is referenced here - https://support.apple.com/HT202867

Comment: So am I having a deadlock here lol? The encryption is taking so long because there is no real space while I cannot add more free space because the encryption is running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I doubted, it was the Encryption which caused the issue with purgeable space. Basically, when your Mac is encrypting the disk, you cannot remove some big files to get free space (perhaps they are being encrypted and Mac do not remove them immediately). Because of my low free disk space, the encryption is taking so long to complete. I patiently waited for it to finish and all purgeable space become free space automatically (it is now more than 60GB).

Answer (score 4):

Oddly enough I had just under 60GB of purgable space.

I read around and found a few posts where people mentioned creating large files as once you ran out of space osx would start using purgable space. It works but you don't need to!

You can **run bootcamp assistant- it will remove local time machine backups AND icloud cached content.** Not only did i get my 60GB purgable space back, but i got an additional 60GB.

Considering I'm on a 250GB SSD and want to dual boot, extremely pleased. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The purgeable space is your main issue. I don't know how the failed encryption is going to complicate things but you can use the info at the following link to get rid of your purgeable space:

https://www.jackenhack.com/mac-os-remove-purgeable-high-sierra/

Best of luck.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.